# After compile install php 5.3.1, I can not find my php.ini file

Tags: php5

my compile configuration:

```
./configure \
--with-fpm \
--with-libevent=shared,/usr/lib \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-zlib \
--with-curl  \
--enable-mbstring \
--with-openssl \
--with-mysql \
--with-mysql-sock \
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--without-sqlite
```

phpinfo page output seems like below

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         none
```

And there is no php.ini in /usr/local/lib.

My Environment:
   Ubuntu 9.10 64bit, nginx 0.8.32

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the INSTALL file in php-5.3.1.tar.gz:

```
13. Setup your php.ini file:

PHP will use the built-in default values if no php.ini file was
placed in the configuration directory. The default location is
/usr/local/lib, if you prefer your php.ini in another location, use 
--with-config-file-path=/some/path in step 10.

The PHP distribution provides two sample php.ini files, you can use them
by
  cp php.ini-development /usr/local/lib/php.ini
or
  cp php.ini-production  /usr/local/lib/php.ini

If you choose one of these php.ini files be certain to read the list
of changes within, as they affect how PHP behaves.
```

You need to create the php.ini file. This can be done by copying one of the sample files.